# AlamoFire doesn't appear to be doing anything

Tags: alamofire, vapor

I am attempting to write a simple scraper with AlamoFire, vis a vis a server-side Vapor back end. AlamoFire appears to be initiated properly, but I'm not getting any action from the callback handler.

```
import Routing
import Vapor
import Alamofire

public func routes(_ router: Router) throws {
    router.get("scrape") { req -> String in
        let stuff = Stuff(id: nil, sourcecode: "This saves to the database.")
        stuff.save(on: req)
        let q = Alamofire.request("http://sigh-fi.com/test.txt").responseString { response in

            // None of this prints to the terminal.
            print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.response))")
            print("Result: \(String(describing: response.result))")
            print("String: \(String(describing: response.result.value))")

            // ideally I'd like to run...
            // let morestuff = Stuff(id: nil, sourcecode: response.result.value)
            let morestuff = Stuff(id: nil, sourcecode: "This doesn't save to the database, so I'm not even getting that far.")
            morestuff.save(on: req)
        }
        print(q) // prints "GET http://sigh-fi.com/test.txt" as expected
        return "okay"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't tell if this is a Vapor problem, an Alamofire or Swift problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know more about vapor than AlamoFire, but does the callback get actioned if you try `.responseJSON` instead of `.responseString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that Vapor has its own HTTP client library, and it seems to work just fine. Still unsure why Alamofire fell apart, but it's moot.

Thank you for your assistance, Nick.

https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/http/client/